# NTFS hard disk not detected in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, data-recovery, ntfs

I have a 250GB SATA NTFS hard disk which i am trying to access thru a hard disk dock on my Ubuntu machine but i haven't been successful.

Here's what i have done,

1. Used 'dmesg' as directed in [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1444593&page=2&s=4694cf2e5d36f94b986748e99f052521) but there were no reports that a new device was detected
2. Attempting to mount it normally but there is nothing to mount because it cannot even be detected
3. Connect it back to a Windows machine thru a hard disk dock in an attempt to safely remove it but even Windows couldn't detect this hard disk.

Does this mean there really is no more hope for this hard disk ?
I am open to suggestions on what else can i try.

Comment: So you used this hard disk dock on linux and on windows, and it doesn't work anywhere? Maybe it's just broken. Does the disk itself work when connected directly, to linux or windows?

Comment: Neh, does not work when connected directly to a windows machine too. In fact, it could be heard spinning for awhile before it went silent.

Answer (score 0):

So given this information:

1. The (external) hard disk dock, with drive, do not work when connected to Windows or Linux
2. Even outside of the external dock, the hard drive still does nothing when directly connected (via sata/ide) to Windows or Linux
3. The drive is quiet & doesn't even make spinning sounds anymore

That's a broken hard drive.

I've read some people sometimes have a little luck reading almost-broken drives by putting them in a freezer for 30min to an hour, then immediately connecting it to a computer, but it's far from guaranteed to work.

Data recovery companies could try some things (like swap boards or internal parts) to read some data, but it's quite specialized and expensive, just opening the drive up yourself is likely to irreparably damage what's left of it.

Comment: I heard of the freezer thing from Scott Moulton haha....well, let me try and see what works before i finally conclude that it cannot be saved.

Comment: If no spin more likely an electronics issue on PCB.

Comment: See https://youtu.be/qdXW-DUSsh8 and check TVS. IF that's the issue simply removing it (the TVS) may get drive going long enough to rescue the data.

Answer (score 0):

If no spin it *may* be the TVS diode. And if so simply removing the TVS may get the drive going so you can pull the data off. For example see https://youtu.be/qdXW-DUSsh8. Applying some flux and using hot air is a more elegant solution to remove TVS but if it works, it works.

Once you recovered the data get rid of the drive or solder a working TVS back on.